# How to turn on the phone flashlight with Qpython?

Tags: python, sl4a, qpython

I coded a Python program to make time laps with the Androidhelper library, only I have one last problem: turn on the light of the phone when it is dark

I have searched the documentation of Androidhelper but it seems to me that you can't control the light with it

Do you have a solution? Can you help me?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.